# Testing a server for security vulnerabilities

Tags: security, web-services, web-server

I'm looking for a **good** tool (software or web service) which can check a Windows web server for possible vulnerability issues. The more the better. (Checking from outside, by a given IP address, but possibly also from inside.)

I see there are a lot of web services out there, but:

1. I'm not sure whether I can trust them
2. I'm not sure if they are really good and reliable

Comment: This is way too broad. It's impossible to scan for all possible vulnerabilities. Some vulns haven't even been found yet.

Comment: I agree that it's broad, but I don't think it's so broad that it needs to be closed.  I think the OP probably realizes that vulnerability detection tools are not perfect.

Comment: @MarkHulkalo: "the more the better" slightly indicates that OP is aware that some (unknown and even known) vulnerabilities may not be detected.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Metasploit](https://www.metasploit.com)?

Comment: @MarkHulkalo I didn't mean to check for "unknown vulns". Mainly, what I am looking for is to have a kind of "sanity check" for a server which looks for common known issues. For example, it could discover if some default Wordpress account has a "common password" or something similar. I just want to be sure that I have not overseen some detail and that I don't have a backdoor open without knowing it. I'm quite a good  C#/SQL developer and so I know about SQL injection and such, but I lack the broad knowledge of a server admin.  I am simply not sure if my system is really save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de-facto tool for this is [Metaploit](https://www.metasploit.com/). It currently has support for 1200 exploits of which ~900 apply to Windows.

You'd typically run Metasploit from a [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) via the Metasploit console `msfconsole`. From there you `use` an exploit, `set` a target, `set` payload and `exp`loit it.

Must have resource: the [SANS Metasploit cheat sheet](https://www.sans.org/blog/sans-pen-test-cheat-sheet-metasploit/)

Metasploit (the command line version, I have no experience with the paid versions) is not self-explaining, so you might take an online course, e.g. [Penetration Testing and Ethical Hacking with Kali Linux](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/kali-linux-penetration-testing-ethical-hacking/table-of-contents) at Pluralsight (there's a free trial that should be sufficient to watch this one).

---

Note that the default download page [[1]](http://www.rapid7.com/products/metasploit/download.jsp) just distinguishes between the community edition and the Pro version but if you look at the editions page [[2]](http://www.rapid7.com/products/metasploit/editions.jsp) there is also the "framework" edition, which is the command line tool used by security analysts and released as open source (BSD license).

If you extract the `.tar.bz2` archive, make sure your **virus scanner is turned off** or excludes the directory you're extracting to, otherwise the virus scanner will quarantine many of the files, since they are known to be threats.

Comment: Metasploit is an ok tool for demonstrating to skeptical bosses how simple it is to get access to their systems. It is most definitely not a tool I'd use to identify new vulnerabilities because **it only knows what's been written for it**. Now, modules get updated pretty quickly, so it does have value - but **never** rely on it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: As I read the question, OP is not looking to identify new vulnerabilities but test a server against known vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hmmm - not how I read it at all. He used the wording I usually get from folks who don't understand how security testing works.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: exactly. So you don't expect someone like that to discover new vulnerabilities, right?

Comment: Thank you! Metasploits looks very good! @RoryAlsop - well, I'm mainly a developer, so I know about open ports, about SQL Injection, good passwords. But I lack the knowledge of a good server admin. I'm running a Windows Server 2008, with RDP and Wordpress, and I just would be sure that it is "safe". Lately, I've seen are lots of tries to break in via ftp (I closed it now), so I'm a little bit concerned. Possibly it would be best to hire some expert I can trust.

Answer (score 2):

#### Vulnerability scanners

Web penetration testing tools (scanners/crawls):

- [WebCruiser Web Vulnerability Scanner](http://www.janusec.com/) - an effective web penetration testing tool that will aid you in auditing your website.
- [Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) - the web-application vulnerability scanner.
- [Nikto](https://cirt.net/Nikto2) - web server scanner to look for potentially dangerous files/programs.
- [SecApps](https://secapps.com/)/[WebSecurify](http://www.websecurify.com/) - Online Vulnerability Scanner & Security Tools.
- [Skipfish](https://code.google.com/archive/p/skipfish/) ([GH mirror](https://github.com/spinkham/skipfish)) - web application security reconnaissance tool.
- [inspathx](https://code.google.com/archive/p/inspathx/) ([GH mirror](https://github.com/Snipercatz/inspathx)) - Tool For [Finding Path Disclosure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Full_Path_Disclosure) Vulnerabilities.
- [WIVET](https://github.com/bedirhan/wivet) - a benchmarking project that aims to statistically analyze web link extractors.
- [Arachni](https://github.com/Arachni/arachni) - Web Application Security Scanner Framework.
- [Nagios](https://exchange.nagios.org/) with some [security plugins](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Security).
- and [so on](https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/tags/scanner/).

No longer being maintained:

- [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) - a proxy to sniff the HTTP(S) traffic with feature for testing XSS and SQL injection vulnerabilities), or "CRLF injection (HTTP response splitting)" and more.

Commercial:

- [Netsparker](https://www.netsparker.com/web-vulnerability-scanner/) - (free) web application security scanner
- [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/) (PortSwigger) - security testing of web applications.
- [Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner](http://www.acunetix.com/) (paid) - scans for SQL Injection, XSS, XXE, SSRF, Host Header Attacks & over 3000 other web vulnerabilities.
- [AppSpider](https://www.rapid7.com/products/appspider/) (NTOSpider) - web application security scanner.
- [HP WebInspect](http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/software-solutions/webinspect-dynamic-analysis-dast/) - an automated dynamic application security testing (DAST) tool that mimics real-world hacking techniques and attacks.
- [IBM Security AppScan](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/appscan) - static and dynamic application security testing.
- [Trustwave](https://www.trustwave.com/Company/Cenzic-is-now-Trustwave/) (Hailstorm) - Cenzic's dynamic application security testing (DAST).
- [Qualys](https://www.qualys.com/free-tools-trials/) - Security & Compliance Suite

Other:

- [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) - a community which issues software tools and knowledge-based documentation on application security. See [wiki page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Project).
- [WhatWeb](https://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/whatweb) - next generation web scanner to identify technologies that power a website, SQL errors, and more.

#### Proxies

- [The OWASP Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP)](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy) - helps you automatically find security vulnerabilities in your web applications (see [wiki](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) page).
- [ratproxy](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ratproxy/) - a semi-automated, largely passive web application security audit tool.
- [Paros](https://sourceforge.net/projects/paros/) - proxy for assessing web application vulnerability.
- [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) with [x5s extension](http://xss.codeplex.com/) to assist penetration testers in finding XSS vulnerabilities or [Watcher](http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/) (passive web-security scanner).

#### SQL Injection

See: [OpenSource Security scan tools for REST APIs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34014/3474)

#### PHP

For PHP malware scanners, see: [Malware scanner for websites code?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32138/3474)